# already exists for an interface other than 'calid41c363

Tags: kubernetes

Today I found the kubernetes 1.26 cluster throw warning message:

> │   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  34s   kubelet            Failed
> to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown ││  desc = failed to
> setup network for sandbox
> "f560512ddd9a8673cf438853ae08dcfe95f40d5271a1dc9090434c130fd8bc5c":
> plu ││ gin type="calico" failed (add): error adding host side routes
> for interface: calid41c363fef4, error: route (Ifindex ││ : 463, Dst:
> 10.97.196.214/32, Scope: link) already exists for an interface other than 'calid41c363fef4': route (Ifi ││ ndex: 25, Dst: 10.97.196.214/32,
> Scope: link, Iface: cali8c8b56cdc6d)
> ││   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  33s   kubelet            Failed
> to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown ││  desc = failed to
> setup network for sandbox
> "719dad86b5b543b6ebf3dd01ece534599c0295d80b7b8444f895c2abe59c6749":
> plu ││ gin type="calico" failed (add): error adding host side routes
> for interface: calid41c363fef4, error: route (Ifindex ││ : 464, Dst:
> 10.97.196.215/32, Scope: link) already exists for an interface other than 'calid41c363fef4': route (Ifi ││ ndex: 21, Dst: 10.97.196.215/32,
> Scope: link, Iface: cali15dbf61b2d1)
> ││   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  20s   kubelet            Failed
> to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown ││  desc = failed to
> setup network for sandbox
> "7a93fd3d10d064928723e2f46f215301535f3337d737077c86ed55c5aeabdbf8":
> plu ││ gin type="calico" failed (add): error adding host side routes
> for interface: calid41c363fef4, error: route (Ifindex ││ : 465, Dst:
> 10.97.196.218/32, Scope: link) already exists for an interface other than 'calid41c363fef4': route (Ifi ││ ndex: 22, Dst: 10.97.196.218/32,
> Scope: link, Iface: cali5d81f78c3a8)
> ││   Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  5s    kubelet            Failed
> to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown ││  desc = failed to
> setup network for sandbox
> "58c8d055e418563f4b6123fd68d7f7ecef4a32fd39d7b56015e231516652b4db":
> plu ││ gin type="calico" failed (add): error adding host side routes
> for interface: calid41c363fef4, error: route (Ifindex ││ : 466, Dst:
> 10.97.196.221/32, Scope: link) already exists for an interface other than 'calid41c363fef4': route (Ifi ││ ndex: 5, Dst: 10.97.196.221/32,
> Scope: link, Iface: caliea71e80a69e)

why did this happen? what should I do to avoid this issue? this is the calico deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: calico-kube-controllers
  namespace: calico-system
status:
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2023-10-04T06:26:45Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-10-04T06:26:45Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2023-10-04T06:26:45Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-10-04T06:26:29Z'
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: >-
        ReplicaSet "calico-kube-controllers-6bb4dc59c7" has successfully
        progressed.
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: calico-kube-controllers
  template:
    metadata:
      name: calico-kube-controllers
      namespace: calico-system
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: calico-kube-controllers
        k8s-app: calico-kube-controllers
      annotations:
        hash.operator.tigera.io/system: bb4746872201725da2dea19756c475aa67d9c1e9
        hash.operator.tigera.io/tigera-ca-private: 8766b9b7cef0ba4722da2eb519044c7c3b68df33
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: tigera-ca-bundle
          configMap:
            name: tigera-ca-bundle
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
        - name: calico-kube-controllers
          image: docker.io/calico/kube-controllers:v3.26.1
          env:
            - name: KUBE_CONTROLLERS_CONFIG_NAME
              value: default
            - name: DATASTORE_TYPE
              value: kubernetes
            - name: ENABLED_CONTROLLERS
              value: node
            - name: FIPS_MODE_ENABLED
              value: 'false'
            - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
              value: 10.96.0.1
            - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT
              value: '443'
            - name: CA_CRT_PATH
              value: /etc/pki/tls/certs/tigera-ca-bundle.crt
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: tigera-ca-bundle
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/pki/tls/certs
            - name: tigera-ca-bundle
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
              subPath: ca-bundle.crt
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /usr/bin/check-status
                - '-l'
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 6
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /usr/bin/check-status
                - '-r'
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            privileged: false
            runAsUser: 999
            runAsGroup: 0
            runAsNonRoot: true
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: calico-kube-controllers
      serviceAccount: calico-kube-controllers
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
          effect: NoSchedule
        - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
          operator: Exists
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
```

I have already fond the similiar issue from here https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/1253.